# Equations for Intersection of Plane and circle

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

I am having a problem in getting the related equations for an intersection between a point on a plane and the edge of a circle in 3D space. Any suggestions?

Or also a tangent plane and a point on a the circle.

Comment: It's not clear specifically what you need.  Do you have equations?  Or do you have a word problem and need to find the equations?   Or something else?

Comment: Hi John, what am trying to specify is, I am trying to find the intersection point between a circle and a plane in 3D. What are the steps required to do this. I don't have any particular equations but an assumption of a circle can be taken. Also do I need to parametrization the equations? Am really confused on this. Thank you for your reply